# Join showing error in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to join marketplace product table and product colection table in magento.But i am not getting the output.here is my code

```
 $showcaseproducts1       =   $showcaseCat->getProductCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                                ->addFieldToFilter('showcase',array('eq' => 1))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq' => 1))
                                ->setOrder('price', 'DESC')->setPageSize(15)
                                ->setCurPage(1);
    $showcaseproducts1     = $showcaseproducts1->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('mp' => $showcaseproducts1->getTable('marketplace_product')), "mp.mageproductid  =e.entity_id", array('*'));
    $showcaseproducts1->addFieldToFilter('mp.userid',array(array('eq' => 163)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $showcaseproducts1 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addFieldToFilter('showcase',array('eq' => 1))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('eq' => 1))
        ->setPageSize(6);

    $showcaseproducts1->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('mp' => $showcaseproducts1->getResource()->getTable('marketplace_product')),
            "e.entity_id=mp.mageproductid"
        )
        ->where('mp.userid=163');
```

Try this code.

Comment: wow...it works....thank u so much Athul